# Changing Button Appearance On Click

Tags: python, button, tkinter

In my GUI application I create a button for every item in a given list. When a button is pressed the background of said button turns green and it appears as "sunken". The other buttons appear raised and with the default color. My issue is that only the last button created changes color and appearance. I believe this is because it contains the callback function.

I desire that after the initial button press, when a user presses a different button that the new button turns green and appears sunken and the previous button becomes raised and the default color. My guess is that I need to create a list of all created buttons and apply logic to it in the callback function for my desired behavior. But how so?

```
# ---callback functions---
def select_button():
    btn.config(bg='green', activebackground='green', relief=SUNKEN)

# ---main---
# List of buttons to be created
list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
buttons = []

# Create buttons
for i, name in enumerate(list, 2):
    btn = Button(root, text=name, command=select_button)
    btn.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W)
    buttons.append(btn)
```

Comment: I know that the default background color of a button is light grey.

Comment: after `for-loo` variable `btn` keeps only last button so using `btn.config` you change only last button.

Comment: this elements have nothing to do with problem but next time don't change question because other read question and comment and they may not understand what's going on. Better add explanations/modifications in question below original version.

Comment: I delete old comments.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using a `Radiobutton` with `indicatoron` set to False, which does almost exactly what you describe: only one in a set of buttons can be selected, and it appears sunken while the rest appear raised. Are you interested in a solution that uses the `Radiobutton` widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was so many times on Stackoverflow so I don't know if I should write it again.

`Button` has `command=` to assign function but it can assign function without arguments. If you need with arguments you have to use `lambda`. I assign function with reference to button so function can use correct button and change it.

`lambda` in `for-loop` needs `arg=btn` and `select_button(arg)` because direct `select_button(btn)` will use last button in all functions.

---

As for changing previous button to original color you can use variable to remember previusly clicked button and then you can easily change it color.

Problem can be to find oryginal color of button so I copy it from new clicked button.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def select_button(widget):
    global previously_clicked

    if previously_clicked:
        previously_clicked['bg'] = widget['bg']
        previously_clicked['activebackground'] = widget['activebackground']
        previously_clicked['relief'] = widget['relief']

    widget['bg'] = 'green'
    widget['activebackground'] = 'green'
    widget['relief'] = 'sunken'

    previously_clicked = widget

# --- main ---

names = ['Button A', 'Button B', 'Button C']

root = tk.Tk()

previously_clicked = None

for i, name in enumerate(names, 2):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=name)

    btn.config(command=lambda arg=btn:select_button(arg))
    #btn['command'] = lambda arg=btn:select_button(arg)

    btn.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use `Radiobutton` with some options to do the same - and without function:

see: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def select_button():
    print('value:', v.get())  # selected value

# --- main ---

names = ['Button A', 'Button B', 'Button C']

root = tk.Tk()

v = tk.IntVar()  # variable for selected value

for i, name in enumerate(names, 2):
    btn = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=name, variable=v, value=i)  # assign variable and value

    btn['indicatoron'] = 0  # display button instead of radiobutton
    btn['selectcolor'] = 'green' # color after selection

    btn['command'] = select_button  # function without variables

    btn.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w', ipadx=5, ipady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, this is a common question but my case is different. How do I change the appearance of the initial button after a new button is pressed? This initial button should be configured to its original state.

Comment: now I see what you need. - you can use variable to remember previously clicked button and then you can change it to oryginal value.

Comment: I add example with `Radiobutton`

Comment: I thought about using radio buttons instead of buttons but did not know about `btn['indicatoron']`. I like that they look like buttons but act as radio buttons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up defining a function within a function to solve my problem. In your case, we would get this :

```
import tkinter as tk

def select(btn):
    def select_button():
        for other_btn in buttons:
            deactivate(other_btn)
        btn.config(bg='green', activebackground='green', relief=tk.SUNKEN)
    return select_button

def deactivate(btn):
    btn.config(bg='gray', activebackground='gray', relief=tk.RAISED)

list_ = ['A', 'B', 'C']
buttons = []

root = tk.Tk()

for i, name in enumerate(list_, 2):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=name) 
    btn['command'] = select(btn)
    btn.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    buttons.append(btn)

root.mainloop()
```

The important part here is the fact that we bypass the difficulty of not being able to pass arguments to button['command'] by defining a function which directly integrates those arguments instead.