# Change button color on click among similar multiple buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Let me elaborate the process. Following is the sample code snippet of my application

```
import tkinter as tk
class ldo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.appOutline()

    def appOutline(self):
        self.masterframe1 = Frame(self.master,width=300,height=300)
        self.masterframe1.grid(sticky=N,padx=20)

        self.masterframe2 = Frame(self.master,width=300,height=100)
        self.masterframe2.grid(sticky=S,padx=20)

        self.addtabbutton = Button(self.masterframe2,text="Add Step", width=10, command=self.popup2, bg="sienna1")
        self.addtabbutton.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=EW)
        self.runallbutton = Button(self.masterframe2,text="Run All", width=10, command=self.underprocess, bg="sienna1",state=DISABLED)
        self.runallbutton.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=EW)
        self.runselbutton = Button(self.masterframe2,text="Run Selected", width=10, command=self.popup2, bg="sienna1",state=DISABLED)
        self.runselbutton.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=EW)

    def popup2(self):
        self.child = Toplevel()
        self.child.geometry("300x300")
        self.child.title("Secondary")

        self.label1 = Label(self.child,text="Your input")
        self.label1.pack()

        self.entryinp = StringVar()
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.child,textvariable=entryinp)
        self.entry1.pack()

        self.submit = Button(self.child,text="Submit",command=self.evaluation,bg="pink")
        self.submit.pack()

    def evaluation(self):
        self.inputValue = self.entry1.get()

        self.steps = Button(self.masterframe1,text=self.inputValue,command=self.colorchange,bg="light blue")
        self.steps.pack()

        self.runallbutton.config(state=NORMAL) 
        self.child.destroy()

    def colorchange(self):
        self.steps.config(bg="white")
        self.runselbutton.config(state=NORMAL)

    def underprocess(self):
        print("processing...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ldo()
    app.master.title("Primary")
    app.mainloop()
```

Below screenshot is the output of my app. My need is I want to change the colour of button I click in Primary interface, but what happens is whatever the button I click, it is changing colour of the last button. I tried using lambda, but I doubt if I am using it correctly. The above snippet is working except the colour change part. Please guide me on how to get this done.

Also, I want "Run Selected" button to print (text of) that particular button I clicked.

P.S.: I have checked in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387155/changing-button-appearance-on-click) too yet not solvable.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `lambda` or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and pass the instance of the boton as argument. Instead of setting the callback when the button is instantiated (the reference does not yet exist) you can use the `config` method. On the other hand you can use an instance attribute to store the references of the selectable buttons (`self._step_buttons` in the code below, a list) and another attribute that stores the reference of the selected button (`self._step_selected` in the code below).

The code could look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial



class Popup2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.geometry("300x300")
        self.title("Secondary")

        self.entry_input = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self, text="Your input").pack()
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_input).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.evaluation, bg="pink").pack()

    def evaluation(self):
        input_value = self.entry_input.get()
        self.master.add_step(input_value)
        self.destroy()


class Ldo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self._step_buttons = []
        self._step_selected = None
        self.grid()
        self.app_outline()


    def app_outline(self):
        self.masterframe1 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=300, height=300)
        self.masterframe1.grid(sticky=tk.N, padx=20)

        self.masterframe2 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=300, height=100)
        self.masterframe2.grid(sticky=tk.S, padx=20)

        self.addtabbutton = tk.Button(self.masterframe2, text="Add Step", width=10,
                                      command=self.open_popup, bg="sienna1")
        self.addtabbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.runallbutton = tk.Button(self.masterframe2, text="Run All", width=10,
                                      command=self.process_all, bg="sienna1", state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.runallbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.runselbutton = tk.Button(self.masterframe2, text="Run Selected", width=10,
                                      command=self.process_selected, bg="sienna1", state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.runselbutton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.EW)

    def open_popup(self):
        Popup2(master=self)

    def add_step(self, step):
        btn = tk.Button(self.masterframe1, text=step, bg="light blue")
        btn.configure(command=partial(self.select_button, btn))
        btn.pack()
        self._step_buttons.append(btn)
        self.runallbutton.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def select_button(self, button):
        if self._step_selected == button:
            self._step_selected.config(bg="light blue")
            self._step_selected = None
            self.runselbutton.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        else:
           if self._step_selected:
               self._step_selected.config(bg="light blue")
           button.config(bg="white")
           self._step_selected = button
           self.runselbutton.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def process_all(self):
        print("Processing all: ")
        for btn in self._step_buttons:
            print("  Processing {}...".format(btn["text"]))

    def process_selected(self):
        print("Processing selected: ")
        print("  Processing {}...".format(self._step_selected["text"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Ldo()
    app.master.title("Primary")
    app.mainloop()
```

I have modified other things, for example, I have provided a toggle button behavior for the buttons.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That's so absolute.. I had never tried with partial functions.. Do you even have any idea of implementing this in any other way.. Also, can you please tell me how did you get this thought process.. that would be more helpful to me as I want to learn